# Find a submersion $\varphi :U\to \mathbb{R}^{n-m}$ such that $\varphi^{-1}(\{0\})=M$ in which $M\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is smooth submanifold

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

Let $M\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be a $m$-dimensional smooth submanifold. We can prove that for all $p\in M$ there're an open neighborhood $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ of $p$ and a submersion $\varphi :U\to \mathbb{R}^{n-m}$ such that $\varphi^{-1}(\{0\})=U\cap M$.

**My question is:** can we prove that  for all $p\in M$ there're an open neighborhood $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ of $p$ and a submersion $\varphi :U\to \mathbb{R}^{n-m}$ such that $\varphi^{-1}(\{0\})=\color{red}{ M}$?

I tried to answer the above question using the partition of unity but I failed. I also don't know any counterexample.

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Not true as stated (though it's a bit of a technicality): If $M$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (for instance an open disk embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$), then $\varphi^{-1}(0)=M$ can't happen, since the first set is closed by continuity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $M$ is globally defined by as the preimage of $0\in \mathbb{R}^{n-m}$ under a submersion $\phi$ then the [normal bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_bundle) of $M$ has a global frame defined by $(\operatorname{grad} \phi_1, \ldots, \operatorname{grad} \phi_{n-m})$, so it's trivial. This imposes some conditions on the manifold. In particular it has to be orientable ( since the ambient $\mathbb{R}^n$ is). I am not sure whether the triviality of the cotangent bundle implies the existence of a globally defined equation, but I am inclined to think so.

As a concrete example, take a non-orientable manifold like the Klein bottle imbedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

$\bf{Added:}$ The condition is also sufficient. As @Kajelad: indicated, we should consider a [tubular neighborhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tubular_neighborhood) $U$ of $M$, which is diffeomorphic to the total space of the normal bundle. If the bundle is trivial, we can define $\phi= (\phi_1, \ldots, \phi_{n-m})$ ( the pullbacks of the coordinates in a trivialization) to define $M$ locally on $U$ as $M= M\times \{0\} = \{ \phi=0\}$.

Comment: The converse is indeed true, provided we're talking about embedded submanifolds. You can construct the submersion using the trivialization of $NM$ and a tubular neighborhood of $M$.

Comment: @Kajelad: I think it should work. So an open tubular neighborhood is diffeo to the total subspace of the normal bundle, so I can define  $\phi = (\phi_i)$ on that tubular. OK, I can extend them to the whole $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Now I see that the natural condition is $\phi$ is a submersion on a nbhd of $M$. To be a submersion everywhere is a bit excessive.  Perhaps I should mention that.  Thanks for the input!